# BBM SDK - Dependency Checker - Packaging the proxy and app

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-world

I have developed the app implementing the functionality of Dependency Checker. Now i am having two application, one is my proxy application which checks the BBM version and other is my real application which should be loaded after BBM Version checking. I tested the ap working installing onto the phone.

Can anyone help me how i can package these files into one and uploading to BlackBerry World.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Hope this works.... after researching i came to know copying the cod files into a zip and uploading it to BlackBerry World.... Lets check what will happen. :)

Comment: Were you able to upload your application successfully to App World?